# Exception while running project

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-tabhost

I am getting this exception while running project

```
2012-07-12 21:29:43 - android.tabcontrol.MainActivity] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/ksoap2/serialization/MarshalFloat;
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
    at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:486)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:180)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:703)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1000)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:854)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:937)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1141)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
[2012-07-12 21:29:43 - android.tabcontrol.MainActivity] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2012-07-12 21:29:43 - android.tabcontrol.MainActivity] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Now what to do..

Comment: *"Now what to do.."* - Well, you could start by sharing _any_ actually information about the code.  Does this happen for every project?  Just a specific one?  What makes that one different?  If you create a new project and start adding functionality rom this one to that one, at what point does the error happen?  Basically, what's the code that's causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're including a class twice, either by having it in multiple `jar` files, or by having it in a `jar` file and in your `src` directory (or any other combination).

Look for the class `MarshalFloat` or the library `ksoap2` and make sure there's only one occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

and additionally you are not allowed to use same library with different name.